# Visual Studio/Sourcesafe checkout problem

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

After a branch was created of a project I was working on, I don't seem to be able to checkout resource files anymore.  I checked the sourcesafe with the administration tool, and I have sufficient rights on the project.  I can checkout the files straight from sourcesafe, but I can't checkout the files from visual studio.  anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Start with File/Source control/Change Source Control and make sure you have things bound correctly for your project.

Comment: Yep, first port of call for me. I always copy that menu option onto the main toolbar for frequent access. :-)

Comment: I did.  Things seem up to par there.  I can check out every other file, just not those resource files :/